# win32api.RegOpenKeyEx failed with errorcode 2 sometimes

Tags: python, registry, pywin32

Below is my code to read registry hive. But I met one odd thing. Sometimes the function works, sometimes not(return error code 2). I noticed that if I use regedit to view the registry key first, then close the regedit, then run the script again, it works. Did anyone meet such error before?

Below is my function.

```
def _getMusicRegistryValue(self, keyName ):
    value  = ""
    aKey = None
    try:
        HKLMKey = win32api.RegConnectRegistry(None, win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
        qqMusic = r"SOFTWARE\\Tencent\\QQMusic"
        aKey = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(HKLMKey, qqMusic)
        #print 'aKey = ',aKey
        (value,valueType) = win32api.RegQueryValueEx(aKey, keyName)
        #installPath = "%sQQMusic.exe" %install
        #print installPath
    except Exception as data:
        self.logger.error('*FAIL*: Exception happened when reading registry hive.Exception details: %s' %data)
        errMsg = win32api.FormatMessage(data[0])
        self.logger.error(errMsg)
        #raise Exception("Read registry failed, QQMusic is not installed.")
    finally:
        if aKey is not None:
            win32api.RegCloseKey(aKey)
            #print 'close key'
        if HKLMKey is not None:            
           win32api.RegCloseKey(HKLMKey)
    return value
```

I have tried to close all the key handlers, but it still has some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Error 2 happens when they key is not present so you should check in the script that indeed the key you are looking for is there.

Also, while using the win32api is correct I would advice you to use _winreg (winreg in python 3) since it is in the standard library and won't make you add the win32api dependency.

There is a possible bug in the code if the application QQMusic is an x86 application in a x64 machine since you will have to also look in the WoW64

Comment: Thank you Mandel. You are right. I mistakenly used \\ in the reg path, which should be \